# Obtener dirección de archivo con mas de un disco duro

Tags: python, python-3.x, os

Estoy trabajando en un programa con Python 3 y necesito crear y buscar archivos en el directorio de trabajo pero cada ves que cargo algo tengo que especificar la ruta completa, normalmente se puede solo dar el nombre y mientras el archivo este en el mismo directorio normalmente lo encuentra pero en mi caso la búsqueda siempre se da en C: y el programa esta en D:.

Intente solucionar esto empleando os:

import os

ruta = os.getcwd()

que en teoría al mostrarlo en pantalla debería mostrar D:\programapy pero en su lugar muestra C:\Users\nombre (si, es Windows ya me ocupare de poner la ruta en el formato correcto luego)
no se si existe alguna manera de que la ruta me de el directorio donde esta el programa (en el disco duro secundario) en lugar de darme la ruta la usuario (que esta en el disco principal)

Comment: La mejor opción es "recordar" la última ruta usada y ofrecerla como opción cada vez que busques un archivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.getcwd()` devuelve el directorio de trabajo, es decir, desde dónde se está ejecutando el script. Si lo que quieres es recuperar el path del script que estás ejecutando deberías poder hacerlo con `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`